# Macro runs faster when run from developer pane, but extremley slow when called from userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am run the same piece of VBA code in Excel in two different ways.
 1. From the developer tab, takes less than 2 sec.
 2. Calling the macro from a userform, takes over a minute and freezes

Here is the code:

```
Sub Import()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim source As String
Dim dest As String
Dim r As Range
Dim msg As String


source = Worksheets("Set-Up").Range("B11")
dest = Worksheets("Set-Up").Range("B8")

Set wbSource = Workbooks(source)
Set SourceSheet = wbSource.Worksheets("HFL01 Extract")
Set wbDest = Workbooks(dest)
Set TargetSheet = wbDest.Worksheets("INPUTS1")

    With SourceSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        For Each r In TargetSheet.Range("A1:N1") 'Range("A1:cc1")
            Set c = .Rows(1).Find(r.Value, , , xlWhole, , 0)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                .Columns(c.Column).Copy
                r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            End If
        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

Set fileDialog = Nothing
Set wbSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Why does running the macro in different ways cause it to be slow? How do I make the macro run at the same speed when called from the userform?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line in your code and run in from the userform again just to check if you actually call the same sub. If this is the code you call it shouldn't hang for minutes.

Comment: I tried adding a breakpoint and ran it from the userform, and it does call the proper function.

Comment: You're iterating a range and involving the clipboard (which shouldn't be needed to overwrite formulas in-place with their respective values) - consider extending the `Find` area to the `CurrentRegion` you're iterating, and looping until `Find` returns `Nothing`: there's no need to iterate each row individually. As for the slowdown, could be `Application.ScreenUpdating` being `True` causing constant redraws since there's now a form displayed. Try setting it to `False` (and back to `True` once done).

Comment: Ill piggyback off of @MathieuGuindon - all those range objects could be done in memory. You could easily rewrite this to not interact with the excel application until the very end.

Comment: Also `r` for a variable representing a cell in row 1 is... confusing, at best.

Comment: I did as @MathieuGuindon suggest by turning Application.ScreenUpdating to True, and that solved the issue of speed! It ran almost instantly. Thanks!

Comment: Note that it doesn't make your code any more *efficient* - it only makes Excel stop redrawing. There's quite a bit of room for actual efficiency enhancements here, feel free to post your (entire) code on [codereview.se] if you'd like feedback on any/all aspects of the code, and learn a bunch of new concepts.

Comment: That makes sense. I am relatively new to VBA so I know there are many enhancements I can make to the code, and it always helps to get a second eye to look at it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Could you expand a little further what lines of code I would change to update the Find area to the Current Region. This is a code I adapted from someone else, and I am still pretty new to VBA.

Comment: Don't worry about it for now, so long as it works as intended, it being inefficient will definitely be fully addressed in details over on Code Review!